# Deep zoom through a web service

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a set of images I retrieve through a web service.

Is there a way to replace these with deep zoom?  Obviously there is a lot more data for a deep zoom image so I would only want to grab what is needed at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MultiScaleImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.multiscaleimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control to do deep zoom in Silverlight.  See the [documentation for deep zoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for how that's accomplished and how to set up your input.

Comment: And this can be used with a web service serving pieces of the data at a time as opposed to having the image data?